# Find IP address from a MAC address

Tags: arp, mac-address

Is there anyway to find the IP address of a MAC address using a command? I was thinking something like `arping` might work but can't seem to find much information on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the NIC owning the MAC is on the same network: Yes.
ArpPing will work.
Listing the arp cache (on windows via `arp -a`) might also work, but only if your PC has communicated with the other NIC in the last minute. It has the advantage that you do not need to install extra software.

If the PC is not only the local network it gets a lot trickier. You might need to log into  switches. What you can do and which commands you need for that differ per device.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a few ways. If on a DHCP server and the client in question is getting an address, the mac will be listed in the lease information in the DHCP console or database.

If the client is attached to a Cisco switch, you could check the sh arp output on the switch and see if the mac is listed.

```
6509-Access-1#sh arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.1.105           0   0017.59ae.fd42  ARPA   GigabitEthernet1/2
Internet  192.168.1.106           -   001d.e6e4.2400  ARPA   GigabitEthernet1/2
Internet  192.168.1.97            1   0022.0dce.e442  ARPA   GigabitEthernet1/1
Internet  192.168.1.98            -   001d.e6e4.2400  ARPA   GigabitEthernet1/1
```